# Program errors with "File Not Found" when Run As Administrator

Tags: c#, desktop, administrator

I have a program I'm building in C#. It copies a file from a network drive to your desktop.

```
string desktop = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
File.Copy("T:\\DATS Launcher.exe", desktop + "\\DATS Launcher.exe", true);
```

If I run the program normally, it works.

If I run the program with "Run as Administrator", I get:

```
************** Exception Text **************

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'T:\DATS Launcher.exe'. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

Why might this be occurring?

Comment: What desktop contains when you run it as administrator? MessageBox.Show(desktop);

Comment: I tried running it both normally and with admin. In both cases, the message box showed `C:\Users\username\Desktop`

Comment: Does `T:\ ` exist for the admin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `T:` drive isn't mapped when you're running as an administrator, since it's running as a different user.

So, you should use the UNC path of the `T:` drive, rather than the drive name.

Answer (score 3):

T: seems to be a network drive only mounted for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

Set `string Letter="T";` and `string Path=@"\\server\share";` (except use your server and share...)

Then

```
ProcessStartInfo psi=new ProcessStartInfo(
    "net.exe",
    "use "+Letter+" \""+Path+"\" /persistent:yes");
psi.CreateNoWindow=true; // We don't need a console showing up for this
psi.UseShellExecute=false; // Most likely optional. Required only if you want to
    // mess with the standard input/output of the process.
    // (for example, to check if mapping was successful).

Process prc=Process.Start(psi);
```

You may also want to set `/persistent:no` if it's a single-ish use application, but use your judgement on that.

Hope this helps.